# How to find if a sequence exists using PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to find using PL/SQL if a specific sequence named e.g. MY_SEQ exits. If the sequence exists then drop it and create a new, or else to just create a new sequence.

E.G. (pseudocode)

```
IF EXISTS(MY_SEQ) THEN
BEGIN
   DROP SEQUENCE MY_SEQ;
   CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SEQ...
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
  CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SEQ;
END;
```

Comment: Note that dropping and recreating it will invalidate all objects which depend on it and remove any outstanding grants.  You'd need to put those back as well.  It would be lovely if Oracle supported `ALTER SEQUENCE sequence_name RESET;`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can check the dictionary view `ALL_SEQUENCES` (or `USER_SEQUENCES` if the executing user is the owner), for example:

```
BEGIN
   FOR cc IN (SELECT sequence_name as sequence_exists
                FROM all_sequences
               WHERE sequence_owner = :seq_owner
                 AND sequence_name = :seq_name) LOOP
      -- sequence exists, drop it (at most there will be *one* sequence)
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SEQUENCE XXX';
   END LOOP;
   -- create sequence
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE XXX';
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have several ideas for this (all untested):

1) Oracle normally supports something like `CREATE OR REPLACE`

2) Use one of the system views from the SYS user to check with a SELECT whether the Sequence exists.

3) Use execute_immediate with a `BEGIN .. EXCEPTION ... END` block to drop the object. If it does not exist, an error should occur, which you can ignore.

Comment: #1 does not work for sequences. #3 is correct and the most efficient method.